# What are the theorems on the inevitability of some kind of order in large sets?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

I've read Paulos' *A Mathematician Plays the Stock Market*:

> > [The problem is that if you look hard enough, you will always find
> >     some seemingly effective rule that resulted in large gains over a
> >     certain time span or within a certain sector. (In fact, inspired by
> >     the british economist Frank Ramsey, mathematicians over the last half
> >     century have proved a variety of theorems on the inevitability of some
> >     kind of order in large
> >     sets)](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=KflY-Yz5P8UC&lpg=PA29&ots=NPvAgM9pBD&dq=butter%20in%20bangladesh%20a%20mathematician%20plays%20the%20stock%20market&pg=PA29#v=onepage&q=butter%20in%20bangladesh%20a%20mathematician%20plays%20the%20stock%20market&f=false)

What are these theorems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In particular, the text is referring to [Ramsey Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_theory), an entire area of mathematics.

As a side-note: perhaps [Benford's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law) would be of interest to you.

Comment: Of course, what is "large" in Ramsey Theory tends to be enormous.  It really doesn't say much about such piddling little data sets as
historical stock market prices.

Comment: So, what you suggest?